# How can I contact another user on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

How can I contact another user on Stack Overflow?

I know of users that just did what I need, but they didn't elaborate the answer with details.

Comment: Using `@` replies. Like you can reply to this comment by including `@gunr2171`.

Comment: "*I know of users that just did what I need, but didn't elaborate the answer with details*" - so leave a comment on that answer, and ask for further details. Or, and this is preferred by far, *research*. This is perhaps easier in JavaScript where research can often take the form of 'methodName' and 'mdn' (`node.nodeType mdn`, for example), but I can't believe that other languages don't have similarly authoritative resources available.

Comment: personnaly, I find this question more precise than the duplicate ! The word "PM" used in first post is an abbreviation that, for me,  means "Post Meridian" !

Comment: This is where context matters. PM is a very common abbreviation for "Private Message" similar to, but some old salts may argue separate from, DM or "Direct Message". As the question does not imply relevance to time keeping, instead containing the context clues of "PM another user" on a website with some level of social interaction it would be unreasonable to strictly assume the former. However, no one knows everything and we learn something new every day. When encountering a thing used in an unfamiliar form, search it, and bask in our access to near infinite information! Google binges are fun!

Answer (score 10):

Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you gain the [privilege to comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).  (You can comment on any of your own posts and answers to your own questions without reaching this reputation amount, though.  Feel free to try with this answer)

In addition, you can use `@username` replies in comments to specifically ping a user (though the owner of the post will always be notified).  This will require having the above privilege.  Don't spam this though or use it in irrelevant posts as it can get annoying.  Also, don't do it on random posts; it's normally a good idea to only do it on posts on which they have commented as well.

Comment: Would you please consider adding that it can be considered rude to do this too often, or to just go around looking for that user's posts to 'ping' them?

Comment: what's the threshold on this?  or protocol for pinging users?