# How to request a comment from a closing user?

Tags: support, closed-questions, comment-replies

**Context**

A question at SO has been closed as *'needing details or clarity'*.

I am not a fortune teller, a mind reader or any kind of wizard, I also have no experience with the library the poster uses. Anyway, I managed to understand the core problem in one quick pass across the text, even without reading details of the source provided therein. So I gave an answer (in the comment space, because the 'closed' question doesn't accept normal answers), which apparently satisfied the question's author.

What wonders me most is that two of closing users have much bigger experience than me – measured with reputation points, they are above 6× and above 10× my rep!

I'd like to ask them to specify, what was so over-generalized or unclear in the question, that they decided to close it.

How do I proceed to reach specific users and ask for comments under the specific question?

The suggested duplicate [How can I contact another user on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272503/733637), marked as a duplicate of [Is there a way to PM another user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272503/733637), does not answer my question, because it covers the case of users who published, answered or commented posts, but *not* those who voted to close it and didn't post any answer nor comment to it.

Comment: @yivi Thank you for a prompt reply. I already casted a re-open vote, also edited the question to provide more context (even though the problem source is a quite well known word puzzle, which easily translates to a well known algorithm). So, honestly, I have added something which IMHO was _not_ necessary. That's why I'd like to see a clear message, what other users consider lacking in the question in question (pun intended in the word puzzle context).

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429529/coding-a-word-ladder-in-c) for reference

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297562/how-to-notify-or-message-a-specific-user

Comment: @Nick Yup, that's the question I'm talking about. But I'm not asking for advocacy or other support in this specific case, but rather want to learn a general venue to solve dubts in similar cases. That's why I intentionally omitted the link you posted. :)

Comment: The question reads a lot like a "here's some code that does x, i need to modify it to do y".  And the question is very tough to read because there's a lot of "what is a word ladder" description.  So i can see why 3 people might have voted to close the question.  (This is an observation, not saying whether it serves to be closed or reopened though - i don't know enough c++ to have an opinion on that)

Comment: @psubsee2003 The description was added (by me!) as an explanation, i.e. clarification, of the problem being solved. It was not there when the three closed the question. I added it because the three closers chose a 'needs clarification' reason but they haven't left any suggestion what needs fixing.

Comment: @psubsee2003 What concerns the code, possibly it is not easily legible. Anyway, as you can see from my comments both there and here, I managed to understand the poster's problem and answer it witout referring to the code. Just by reading their description in words, and in return by describing the suggested algorithm and suggesting helpful data structures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I contact another user on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/how-can-i-contact-another-user-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes, it does – partially. The specific situation here is I want to notify a user, who didn't take part in commenting conversation, nor answered the question, in which cases `@name` works well. I'd like to notify users, who have cast close votes, which resulted in closing a question. I mean those mentioned in the blue box message _'Closed <some time ago> by User1, User2, User3.'_. Now [I have tried that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429529/coding-a-word-ladder-in-c#comment110446900_62429529) and I wait for a response. (to be contd.)

Comment: @StephenRauch Alas [meta.stackexchange How do comment `@replies` work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020) suggests it won't work, but let's wait and see... :)

Comment: You don't need to contact any users. Look at the edit history. Here's [how the post looked when it was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62429529/1). It doesn't specify in detail what the code should do or how the date is modeled. There was insufficient info. You came over and figured it our after the OP edited in a fair bit of information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[You can can sometimes @ping close voters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020):

> For questions: The moderator or gold badge holder who closed or reopened the question, provided they were the only one to do so.

Although generally, you can't:

> Users who have closed or reopened a question without a binding close vote (i.e. without a gold tag badge or a moderator vote), and those who bindingly voted, but other users were also involved (e.g. closed by User1, User2, and Moderator) cannot be notified

But if you disagree with a question closure, **better than pinging other users is to use your own votes and editing privileges to hopefully help the question into getting reopened**.

Discussing other user's votes is not particularly productive, better act on the post directly to the best of your judgement and expertise.

Comment: "generally" seems a big stretch since any closure that involved more than 1 person, then the ping no longer works.  So that eliminates any non-duplicate closure unless a mod did it

Comment: You are right psubsee. I read it wrong. Still, not _that_ bad for a monkey. I'll correct the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, I never realized the users who have cast their close votes ('Closed <some time> ago by User1, User2, User3.') are reachable by @ notification tool. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not intend to _discuss_ their point of view, but rather to improve the post, because I consider it worth keeping (and answering and earning rep.points, too! :) ). However, as I said in [the comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398445/how-to-request-a-comment-from-a-closing-user/398446#comment776162_398445), the post is clear and precise enough for me, so I need some specific pointers as to _what_ needs improvement. Hopefully such comments would also allow the original poster to improve their asking skills.

Comment: @CiaPan You appear to have misread what's written here. "The user**s** (plural) who have cast their close votes ('Closed <some time> ago by *User1*, *User2*, *User3*.') are" **not** pingable using `@` pings. The *user* (singular) who closed a question, "*provided they were the only one to do so*", is pingable using `@` pings, but that user's username is not included in the auto-completion of available usernames when you type the `@` in a comment.

Comment: @Makyen timing is important.  The original version of this answer did not make that distinction clear (hence my initial comment).  The answer wasn't edited until a few minutes before CiaPan last comment.  So it might have been some confusing signals

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, there are a variety of possible ways the miscommunication could have happened. However, the answer was edited to add the relevant quote 20 minutes after it was posted. The comment I responded to was posted 40 minutes after that edit. I'm not attempting to assign blame for the miscommunication (who cares?). I was merely trying to correct it. The last information we have from CiaPan indicates there was still a lack of accurate miscommunication after the question was answered and the answer edited. Hopefully the miscommunication is cleared up at this point, one way or another.