# How can an incorrectly closed question be restored, and the closing voters notified?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, new-users, reopen-closed

In 2021 a question asked by a new user was closed by several members with sufficient reputation, but without sufficient experience in the subject matter.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301794/optimal-way-of-combining-two-polygons-and-keeping-distances

[Screenshot of the linked question for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC8sY.jpg)

**How might the question be resurrected, and the closing members notified (reasonably nicely)?**

The manner in which the question was closed could explain why that new member hasn't posted again. The member (reputation 1) appears to have visited SO recently (April/May 2022).

I'd gladly grant the original poster some of my reputation to encourage future participation.

Comment: I mean a good start would be to not call the community's actions unfair and embarrassing while asking them for help.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. A few members of the community did something unfair. The rest of the community is rather large. And if you know something that would help, could you help, please?

Comment: Why does anyone need to be notified? Why don't we just address the issue by re-opening the question (assuming that it was, in fact, wrongly closed, as you claim; there's no way to verify that, since you didn't include a link to the question).

Comment: "I've been a member for 10 years. I'd appreciate a little engagement before you downvote." Sorry, no; that's not how downvoting works. The purpose of downvoting is to give feedback silently, *without* engagement. Also, one's reputation and/or tenure has no effect on voting. Votes are cast on posts, not on users. One would think that after 10 years, you would know how the site works.

Comment: @CodyGray, thank you. Just a moment. As far as verifying, I want the opportunity to interact with whoever does the verification.

Comment: You seem to want to interact with everyone: you want interaction with the people who voted to close, you want interaction with the people who downvote... I'm puzzled by that. That's exactly the opposite of how this site is designed to work. It isn't interactive. It's not a social networking site or a forum. We only do Q&A. The focus is exclusively on the content.

Comment: Link posted in the question.

And yes, I know how the site works, and how some questions are handled, which is one reason why this is the first question I've posted.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. But... that's not even a programming question! Why should it be opened or answered here?

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't want to interact with everyone. It may seem that way to you, which I get, but not my intention.

Comment: @CodyGray, computational geometry is programming. I didn't get half a chance to interact with the OP and the closing members at the time and explain this. It takes a few sentences to explain the connection, introduce the code, etc.

Comment: As one of the original close voters, I stand by my original vote. As Cody says, the question is not about programming as defined in the help center.

Comment: @IanCampbell, but are you familiar with the connection between computational geometry (programming) and the question as posed?

Comment: There's a connection between *everything* and programming, but that doesn't mean we allow questions about everything. Computational geometry questions are only allowed if they're specifically asked *in the context of software development*. This one wasn't.

Comment: @CodyGray, understood, but for a new user who is engaged in a field you know, you wouldn't want to steer them back to programming, which is where they're headed? My intention in using SO is to help individual people. If I can't help individual people--which may not be the explicit intent--then it's hard to keep some of those new users from being frustrated.

Comment: One need not be a world-expert to identify a question (and as an aside answer) that is not about programming. If I asked a question about the structure of DNA on Stack Overflow that had nothing to do with programming, I would trust you to be able to vote to close it.

Comment: @IanCampbell, but if a question about the structure of DNA were asked such that the user was a few days away from (say) solving the answer using programming, what would you do?

Comment: If the author would be asking for help with a specific problem while implementing a computational geometry algorithm, that would be on-topic. But the question only ask only about the computational geometry theory and not about the implementation and that is off-topic. Compare it with a cooking robot: Programming the cooking robot is fine. Asking how to make a burger isn't.

Comment: @BDL, maybe you're very familiar with computational geometry, but the main books in the field all cover implementations in pseudcode (and often in C). Yet there are gaps. The OP identified a gap--something I don't recall having seen asked in quite that way. And I get your point about robots, given my experience, but there is such a thing as programming a robot to cook a burger. :)

Comment: Where is the relevant code?

Comment: I would direct them to ask their question on Biology.SE. Or, if there was already quality content on the Q&A and I was *absolutely* sure, I might flag for moderator migration along with a very detailed explanation.

Comment: We can't really worry about what the asker of a question may or may not do or be motivated to do in the future. That's not our problem or our concern. The purpose of this site, as noted in the [tour], is to build a library/repository of high-quality answers to every question about programming. This isn't a tutorial site or a help desk. If the question isn't about programming, we don't answer it here. And if someone is demotivated by that, I worry about what will happen when they walk into a theatre and demand to have the oil changed in their car.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I could dig it up. Is this important? Noting "computational geometry" is sufficient to indicate the connection between geometry and code. Eberly's book does this very well.

Comment: The main goal of SO is to built a library of high quality questions and answers about programming. Helping individual users may be a by-product of this, but its not the main goal. We should never take into account who the asker is, we only judge the quality/on-topic for the content of a question. Whether the author is new or has 100k rep, whether the author might be heading in the direction of programming is irrelevant.  Don't judge users, judge content!

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks for your response. The first sentence, "This site is all about getting answers," is most relevant. Towards the end is "Remember: we're all here to learn, so be friendly and helpful!" And I could've been more friendly here--granted!--and I'm trying to find a way to have the OP's question restored **somewhere** so that I can continue to be friendly and helpful.

Comment: @BDl, "high quality questions and answers about programming" for people, yes. Some people need a helping hand sometimes. That's my career. A helping hand is sometimes all it takes. Just one.

Comment: Looks like we're all done here. Thanks for all your replies and work. I have what I need.

Comment: @Rethunk: I'm absolutely not against helping people, I'm working at a university and 50% of my work is teaching students and helping them with their individual problems and questions. SO is just not the right place to do this. Neither the mission, nor the q&a format are well suited for a helpdesk. There are plenty of site out their with the mission to help individual users without having the goal to build a library. Please don't try to make SO into one of them.

Comment: What I think many are trying to tell here is that being about computational geometry alone does not make it on-topic *on Stack Overflow*. However, it can very well be on-topic on *other* sites of Stack Exchange network. For example, maybe on Mathematica, they even have a relevant [tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry). Or on Computer Science (same [tag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry)).

Comment: Indeed, what Oleg said. This looks like a high-quality question, and I agree that it deserves a good answer, it just doesn't fit on Stack Overflow because it's not about programming as we define it here. Had you brought this up sooner (either here on Meta, or perhaps with a mod flag), we could have migrated the question from SO to another site on the network where it would be on-topic. We don't migrate low-quality questions, even if they're on-topic (we just close them), but high-quality questions can and should be migrated. There's just a 60-day time limit on it; this one's too old.

Comment: @CodyGray, all, once again--thanks. I'll do something else with the question, just not today. Gotta get back to coding, you know. :)

Comment: @Rethunk you can ask the author to repost it on a correct site or, if they are no longer responsive, IRRC you are allowed to repost it yourself on the target site.

Comment: That seems to me like a pure geometry question unrelated to programming. I'm guessing the question would have been [very welcome here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/geometry/info) and also very likely to receive an adequate answer.

Comment: "*I'd gladly grant the original poster some of my reputation to encourage future participation.*" Reputation is not a participation trophy. It should be earned by good contributions only.

Answer (score 26):

I am one of the close voters. I will attempt to address your questions.

##### 1. How can the question be restored?

It can't; it is not about programming. It may be related to programming, but that is not enough. This question is about geometry, as you note in the comments.

##### 2. How can the close voters be notified.

[We can't be notified](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398445/how-to-request-a-comment-from-a-closing-user). That's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). You took advantage of the best way to bring attention to an issue, to post on Meta (and here I am).

##### 3. How can non-experts vote to close a question?

In a previous revision (and the comments), you noted that I and other close voters are not experts in the field. I can't speak for the other voters, but this is true of me. Nonetheless, I need not be a world-expert to identify that a question is not about programming. I remember carefully reviewing the question and your answer and determined that neither were about *programming*.

##### 4. But it's a good question, can't I answer it?

You **can** answer it, just not on Stack Overflow. [Stack Exchange has hundreds of vibrant communities](https://stackexchange.com/sites), there's almost certainly one where this is on-topic. Often it's faster to direct the question author to ask there question over on the site where it is on-topic. However, if there is existing good quality content on the Q&A, you can try to get the question migrated. The key here is that you need to be *absolutely* sure it is on topic at the destination. You can ask on the [network-wide Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for additional guidance if needed. Once you're sure, you can flag the question as in need of moderator intervention and request migration. Provide a detailed explanation. Unfortunately, this can only take place during the first 60 days of a question's existence.

Answer (score 6):

If indeed this *can* be turned into a question actually about programming, we encourage you to do that. You may want to opt to make the question a "community wiki" one (this terminology is weird; there is no wiki here, but the "community" part is true. You abstain from earning any reputation points from upvotes by checking the "CW" box below the editor pane when you post), especially if you borrow heavily from the original question, which had a fair amount of illustrations etc.

Getting it in front of the original asker may not be possible, but if the question turns out to be valuable in its own right, I'd think that's eventually a secondary concern after all; and if they are active in pertinent tags on the site, chances are they *will* come across it.

Earlier in the question's history, this could have been accomplished by editing the original question, but now, posting a completely separate new question is definitely the way to go. Editing somebody else's closed question into an acceptable question often involves some amount of second-guessing and/or putting words in the original author's mouth, so a fresh independent question from a clean slate is in many ways more straightforward.

For the record, I too am one of the original close voters.